# Finding a reaction norm in R using logistic regression with binomial errors.

Tags: r, data-visualization, regression, generalized-linear-model

I am trying to calculate 'reaction norms' for a fish species. This is essentially the length at which the probability that a fish become mature equals 50% for a particular age class.

I know I have to use a logistic regression model with binomial errors but I can't work out how to calculate this from the summary outputs or plot the regression successfully!

I have a data set that has:
 'age' classes in (1,2,3,4,5,6),'Lngth' data in mm and 'Maturity' data (Immature/Mature - 0/1).

I am running a glm as follows

```
Model<-glm(Maturity~Lgnth, family=binomial(logit))
```

This however does not take into account the different age classes (I would really like to avoid creating whole new data sets for each age classes as I have multiple year ranges to test).

And even so, I do not understand how I interpret the summary output to give me a length at which the probability of being mature equals 50%, along with the standard errors of this figure.

I also can't quite get the code right to plot this.
Ideally id have one plot with lngth along the x axis, probability along the y and six lines/curves representing each age classes.

I would really appreciate any help any one could provide! I know this can all be achieved but I am really struggling.

Cheers

Comment: i had some comments but they disappeared after migration.  (1) Can you post some sample data?  (2) see `MASS::dose.p`; (3) try `Maturity~Lgnth:factor(Age)`

Comment: @BenBolker. I thought I had responded to this but it seems to have disappeared. Thanks for your help! 
I think I have managed to sort a decent model 
`mylogit <- glm(Maturity ~ Lngth + age, data = clupea.data, family = "binomial")`
My question now is, once I have run this how do I use dose.p to calculate length at p50% maturity for each age class?
Is there a way of doing it from this one model `mylogit` or do I have to run an individual model for each age class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll demonstrate computing the reaction norms for a two class problem.  Let's let $p$ denote the probability of maturity predicted by the model, $L$ the measured length of a fish, and $A$ the class variable (which I'm going to assume is two class, to simplify).  Then the logistic model would be something like

$$ \log \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right) = -1 + .5 L + .5 A $$

where $A$ is a coded indicator, $0$ or $1$, say of "young fish" or "old fish".  We want to calculate the cut point at $p = .5$ for both young and old fish.  For young, plugging $p=.5$ and $A=0$ into the equation gives:

$$ 0 = -1 + .5 L \Rightarrow L = 2 $$

For old fish $A=1$, so our equation is

$$ 0 = -1 + .5 L + .5 \Rightarrow L = 1 $$

For your plotting question, I'll show you what I learned from Gellman and Hill's book [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/).  First, let's make some data to model and subsequently plot

```
N <- 250
expit <- function(t) {(exp(t)/(1+exp(t)))}

X <- data.frame(L=runif(N, 0, 6), A=rbinom(N, 1, .5))
p <- expit(-1 + .5*X$L + .5*X$A)
X$y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
```

Fitting a logistic model

```
model <- glm(y ~ L + factor(A), data=X, family="binomial")
print(model)

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ L + A, family = "binomial", data = X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            L     factor(A)1  
    -0.8627       0.4239         0.6917
```

If $A$ had more than two classes, you would see additional parameter estimates like `factor(A)2` and `factor(A)3` etc.

Now here's how to make a nice plot of the data and the probability of maturity for each of the two classes.  First, add some jitter to the y values, so they don't crowd and stack over each other

```
add_jitter <- function(v) ifelse(v == 0, runif(length(v), v, v+.05), runif(length(v), v-.05, v))
y_jitter <- add_jitter(X$y)
```

Then pull off the coefficients of your model

```
co <- coef(model)
```

Then plot

```
plot(X$L, y_jitter, pch=16, col="grey",
     xlab = "Length of Fish", 
     ylab="Probability of Maturity",
     main="Fishies")
curve(expit(co[1] + co[2]*x), add=TRUE)
curve(expit(co[1] + co[2]*x + co[3]), lty=2, add=TRUE)
legend("right", c("Young Fish", "Old Fish"), lty=c(1, 2), bty="n", lwd=2)
```

This looks really nice

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still struggling though I'm afraid. I'm trying to calculate the probability of maturing (p) as a function of length (L).
The equation that i'm trying to work with is 

logit(p) ≈ Co+C1L.

where Co and C1 are the model parameters to be estimated and where the logit link function is given by 
logit(p)=loge[p/(1-p)].

I'm running rings around my self and it is incredibly frustrating.
Again though thanks for your help!

Comment: @StuartDrew  You'll have to fit the model and estimate the parameters first.  Does that help any?

Comment: Is that what you've done in the first block of code in your example?
`X <- data.frame(L=runif(N, 0, 6), A=rbinom(N, 1, .5))
p <- expit(-1 + .5*X$L + .5*X$A)
X$y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)`

Comment: That fist block is me making some fake data to use.  Then I fit a model to this in the second block.  After fitting, you can get the coefficients with `coef(model)` (or whatever the equivalent is in your software of choice), and then proceed with the arithmetic I outlined.

Comment: Cool. How would one go about using the equation I laid out in my first comment?
I mean I have data: two columns with Maturity (0,1) data in one and Length (in mm) in the other. And the model I have been running is looks like this
 `mylogit <- glm(Maturity ~ Lngth, data = data, family = "binomial")`
But how do I go about using the equation to find the probability of maturing as a function of length?
Thanks so much for your help and quick replies by the way!

Comment: No problem.  Just call `coef(mylogit)` to get a summary of the coefficients.  In your case you'll have an intercept coefficient and a length coefficient.  In my example I used `-1` for the intercept and `.5` for the length, but your true values will obviously be different.  Then just go through the math like I did, essentially solving the equation `0 = intercept_coef + length_coef * L` for L.  This is your value of length that gives a probability of one half for maturity.